# Error on serialize lambda function with closured data

Tags: julia

I use code like this:

```
p = _belineInterpolateGrid( map( p -> sin(norm(p)), grid ), grid )
f = open("/data/test.function", "w")
serialize( f, p )
close(f)
p0 = deserialize( open("/data/test.function", "r") )
```

where _belineInterpolateGrid is

```
function _belineInterpolateGrid(PP, Grid)
    ...
    P = Array(Function, N-1, M-1);
    ...
    poly = (x,y) -> begin
        i_x, i_y =  i(x, y);
        return P[i_x, i_y](x, y);
    end
return poly
```

And now, since some of v0.4, a have an error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching
convert(::Type{LambdaStaticData}, ::Array{Any,1})
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor LambdaStaticData(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
convert{T}(::Type{T}, ::T)
 ...
 in deserialize at serialize.jl:435
```

Why It's happend? Is it bug and how to fix it?

Comment: I guess this might be considered a regression since it used to work in 0.3, so please make a small reproducing example and [file a bug](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#how-to-file-a-bug-report). That said, this approach seems a bit strange and is probably slower than it could be. Is there a reason you are not using the built-in parallelization constructs?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in Julia to me, and it looks like it has been fixed as of v0.4.6. Try upgrading to that version or newer and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a lambda, that's why. Can't tell if it's a bug (you can serialize a lambda but you can't deserialize it?).

You can *avoid* this by defining your "get interpolation at x,y" as a type:

```
import Base: getindex
type MyPoly
    thepoly
end

function getindex(p::MyPoly, x::Int, y::Int)
    p.thepoly[x+5*y]
end
function getindex(p::MyPoly, I...)
    p.thepoly[I...]
end
function call(p::MyPoly, v)
    #collect helps keep eltype(ans) == Int
    powered_v = map( i->v^i, collect(
                     take(countfrom(),size(p.thepoly,1))))
    powered_v.*p.thepoly
end


p=MyPoly(collect(1:10))
println(p[1])
f = open("serializedpoly", "w")
serialize( f, p)
close(f)
p0 = deserialize( open("serializedpoly", "r"))
println(p[1,1])

v=call(p, 4) #evaluate poly on 4
```

EDIT: added extension for `call`

Comment: Yes, I can serialize lambda, but can't deserialize it. I'm use something like your solution and it's work, but problem is bigger. For example, I want to set my polynom object callable and define function call(Function, MyPoly). And now I have function for numeric integration: integration(p::Function, a::Float, b::Float). Now I can apply this function for MyPoly, but error will come back. Of course It's possible create definition of interpolation for MyPoly, but this is only a partial solution.

Comment: The thing is (and also, what I'm trying to show) is that you don't have to pack the information and/or parameters inside a lambda. You would have all these in a type, and all behaviour/execution in function calls. The julia way is this: have a container for data and parameters, define behaviour in functions, and extend already defined functions (`convert`, `call`, `index`...)